# How can i make the Bevel tool have the new edges be non linear?

Tags: bevel

I bevel the edge my geometry.
The resulting new edges are always parallel and straight.
How can i make the new edges diverge at an angle or be curves?

I'm not talking about the amount of segments, with 10 segments the outer edges containing the segments will still be parallel.

[image: I want to bevel the edge along the geometry. How can i make the bevel contraint follow the faces until the outer edges?]

Comment: Have you tried scrolling the mouse wheel as you are bevelling to increase the number of segments? You can also change the segments in the botttom-left operator panel after bevelling.

Comment: i just noticed that you can misinterpret my question to deliver this answer^^ i specifically DO NOT talk about the number of segments! i know there will be a "smooth part" between the new edges as soon as i increase the number of segments above 1. my question is how do i manipulate the angle between the 2 new edges that have the new segments between them?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps, it is the online equivalent of shouting, is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) and may be [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing). You can use the [edit] button below to change you text into regular case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my pained understanding of what you're trying to achieve, you should change your bevel mode from `Offset` to `Percent`

First run one bevel operation, then expand the 'last operation panel' on the bottom left of the 3D View

[image: Bevel Options]

Comment: yes thats it! you know why i didnt find that myself? because every other width type immediately converts the amount you already beveled to the new functionality of the other width type. except percent... percent sets the value to 0%. so i assumed "its just one of these features that dont apply to my case because nothing happens"

Answer (score 1):

As always i found an incredibly timeconsuming workaround that does exactly what i want. it involves DELETING the edge i want to bevel and then instead bevel every single vertex where the edge used to intersect with horizontal edgeloops.[image: beveling every single vertex manually...]